# How to use R variables in css code chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown

The [bookdown reference for SQL chunks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#sql) states that:

> If you need to bind the values of R variables into SQL queries, you
> can do so by prefacing R variable references with a ?.

But, how do you use R variables in css code chunks?

Comment: Could you post an example?  It's not clear what you want:  do you want a chunk that outputs CSS that affects the document, or CSS that is displayed because your document is talking about CSS as a language?

Comment: @user2554330 I am talking about a chunk that outputs CSS that affects the document. For example I would like to define the color of an element according to the current bootstrap theme, using something like `bs_get_variables(bslib::bs_current_theme(), "primary")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output CSS code that affects the document, I'd use the `glue` package to do the substitutions, in an R code chunk that has `echo=FALSE, results='asis'`.  For example,

````
```{r css, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
margin <- 40

library(glue)
cat(glue(.open = "<<", .close = ">>", "
<style>
h1 {
  margin-left: <<margin>>px;
}
</style>
"))
```
````

would put the parts between `<style> ... </style>` into your document, substituting for R variables whereever it sees a variable name in double angle brackets, e.g. `<<margin>>` in my example.